# Strange multiple class names in Linderdaum Engine

Tags: c++, class, linderdaum

I am trying to use Linderdaum Engine and found there many strange declarations like:

class scriptfinal netexportable ClassName: public iObject

These strange names `scriptfinal` and `netexportable` are macros. But they are defined to be empty. 
Why someone can need this kind of defines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're empty so that the C++ compiler won't care about them.

The Linderdaum Engine preprocesses the C++ sources in order to generate meta-information about the classes.

Those macros are most likely used by their preprocessor to generate information for their scripting language (`scriptfinal`) and .NET serialization code (`netexportable`).

Comment: They have a preprocessor - LSDC. I removed some of these macros from the source code and rerun the rebuildlsd.py script. The output changed. Seems you are right.

Comment: Just to clarify things, I must say "scriptfinal" denotes classes which may not be derived in script language and "netexportable" actually refers to the classes being marshalled to .NET environment (but also as the serializable ones for historical reasons). And they are empty exactly for the compiler to ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

For example, someone might set the scriptfinal macro to:

```
#define scriptfinal __declspec(dllimport)
```

to get:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) ClassName: public iObject {};
```

Since __declspec is a Microsoft specific extension so normally it is used by macro expansion in portable code. When compiling for the Linux environment the macros are empty so `__declspec` is not visible to the compiler and under Windows they will be defined as above.

Comment: Yes, they are empty now. But they can be changed into non-empty macros easily to generate certain type of code [in different platforms/hardware].

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But why two macros are used?

Comment: I have check the source code and there is no evidence of different defines for Linux/Windows. You are wrong :(

Comment: The macros can be set at compile time by arguments to the compiler.

Comment: @jrok: checked with gcc verbose output - the macros are empty. Anyideas?